# SpriteKit and particle collision

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a particle emitter and I would like to detect it when the particles collide some physics bodies.
Is there a native way to do that in the SpriteKit API or do I need "to cheat" ?

Answer (score 7):

Individual particles can not collide. Not with physics, not any other way. You do not even get any information about an individual particle - you can't access it's position, rotation, velocity .. nothing.

If you wanted to "cheat" you'd have to emulate the particle emitter using sprites, and animate the sprites with actions or manually. However keep in mind that this is much less efficient than a particle emitter.

In addition, if we're talking "particles" which often means dozens or even hundreds of them on screen, the amount of physics processing and collision detection quickly becomes prohibitively expensive if you were to model them using sprites with physics bodies attached. Do a performance test before you go down this path.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for this detailed answer ! Isn't there any other alternative ? Let's say that I want to simulate an explosion, that I'm using particles to do this and that I would like to hurt any character which is touched by that, is there an other way to do that (even if I use something totally different of particle emitter)

Comment: Like I said, if you make the exploding particles sprites you can collide them but you can't animate them as neatly as when using a rule-based system like particle emitters.

Answer (score 3):

Particles do not have physics bodies, so they don't collide with Sprite Kit's physics engine

Answer (score 0):

You can set the physics body of the particle emitter the same way you set it for any sprite node. Then you can set the category bit mask property and the contact test bit mask. The method didBeganContact can detect the collision afterwards.

Comment: Thank you ! But does it call this method for every single particle ? Do you think that it works even when you set a target node for your particle emitter ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work, because particles do not have physics bodies.

Answer (score 0):

didBegan contact is called whenever two bodies contact each other . Here is the apple reference link for how this method works:

Click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPhysicsContactDelegate/didBeginContact:"Apple iOS developer library")!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it to see if it works because although particles are nodes, these are special nodes that are a little bit different. By the way, you seem to be new on StackOverflow, so her's an advice : if you want to add additional information you can do that by editing your original answer. You can also answer directly in comments if someone asked you a question as I just did. (generally you never write two answers)