# SpriteKit Particle Emitter - can particles be affected by forces after creation

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I would like to know if particles can be affected by forces after they are created, such as by wind, or having an object pass through them as they are swirling around or falling or doing whatever they are designed to do during their lifespan. For instance, if there is a simulated snow storm can a car driving through them affect the way they move as they fall?

Comment: Sorry. I found the answer to my question here, I'll look more thoroughly next time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402853/spritekit-and-particle-collision

Comment: But it seems that it can be done with SCNParticleSystem, in case anyone is wondering the same thing.